# Como obter o magnet link de um arquivo .torrent?

Tags: php

Consigo obter informações de arquivos *.torrent* usando a classe [**Torrent RW**](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/24765.html) ou [**Torrent-parse**](https://github.com/BotLife/torrent-parse), como o nome do arquivo, tamanho, *HASH*, etc.

Gostaria de também obter o *magnet link*, porém estou tendo dificuldades para proceder com isto, como posso extrair essa informação usando alguma dessas duas classes?

Comment: nao entendi sua dúvida, é programação?

Comment: Sim, aquelas duas classes que passei apresentam os problemas que citei a cima.

Comment: Lucas, editei a pergunta para deixar ela mais objetiva, do jeito que estava era vaga, por isso a *chuva* de negativos, se a minha edição estiver errada, você pode [revertê-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63355/revisions).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *Torrent RW* não dispõe uma função que retorne o [*Magnet Link*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet-Link). Somente o *Torrent-parse*, através da função `magnet()`. Veja um exemplo:

```php
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
include 'Torrent.php';

$torrent = new Torrent('tails-i386-1.2.3.torrent');

echo "<pre>";
echo "Nome do arquivo: ". $torrent->name()                . "<br>";
echo "Tamanho: ". $torrent->size(2)                       . "<br>";
echo "Piece length: ". $torrent->piece_length()           . "<br>";
echo "HASH: ". $torrent->hash_info()                      . "<br>";
echo 'Privado: '. ($torrent->is_private() ? 'Sim' : 'Não'). "<br>";
echo 'Comentário: '. $torrent->comment()                  . "<br>";
echo 'Anúncio: '. $torrent->announce()                    . "<br>";
echo 'Status: ', var_dump($torrent->scrape())             . "<br>";
echo "Magnet link: ". $torrent->magnet()                  . "<br>";
```

A saída será algo parecido com isto:

```all
Nome do arquivo: tails-i386-1.2.3
Tamanho: 907.67 Mo
Piece length: 262144
HASH: 957a82ee0d2fb0938952167d6c34dbf7e37a8946
Privado: Não
Comentário: 
Anúncio: http://torrent.gresille.org/announce
Status: array(1) {
  ["http://torrent.gresille.org/scrape"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["complete"]=>
    int(239)
    ["downloaded"]=>
    int(8)
    ["incomplete"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}

Magnet link: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:957a82ee0d2fb0938952167d6c34dbf7e37a8946&dn=tails-i386-1.2.3&xl=951765793&tr=http://torrent.gresille.org/announce
```

Comment: Saiu assim para mim

Nome do arquivo: IDMan.exe
Tamanho: 3.71 MB
Piece length: 16384
HASH: 1c59a7e81c0321e6bd5646187fe58354baf91f3c
Privado: Não
Comentário: 
Anúncio: Array
Status: 
array (size=3)
  'http://tracker.ccc.de/scrape' => string 'Tracker request failed (404 code)' (length=33)
  'http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/scrape' => string 'Tracker request failed (302 code)' (length=33)
  'http://tracker.publicbt.com/scrape' => string 'Tracker request timeout (30s)' (length=29)

Comment: @LucasCarezia Acho que você está usando o Torrent RW, use o **Botlife**.