# Como usar a API do Bitsnoop

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso obter os *seeders* e *leechers* de um arquivo *.torrent* usando a [**API**](http://bitsnoop.com/info/api.html) do Bitsnoop. Como posso estar realizando a requisição?

Comment: Do jeito que está a pergunta, ela pode ser fechada por ser muito ampla, qual a é dúvida exatamente? em qual parte você está com dificuldades?

Comment: Reformulei minha pergunta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, mas mesmo assim ela está vaga, futuramente tente postar algum código já feito, postar o que você já tentou, quais as dificuldades você está tendo para fazer isso, enfim, tente postar uma pergunta com um mínimo de esforço, assim haverá mais possibilidades em receber respostas que atendam ao seu objetivo.

Comment: Se possível faça um [**Tour**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site, veja também os tópicos [desta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender como o site funciona. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer uma requisição `GET`, e enviar como parâmetro a chave `hash`, o valor da *HASH* do arquivo *.torrent*, e especificar o formato `json`.

```php
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
include 'Torrent.php';

function obterSeedLeech($hash){
    $apiURL = "http://bitsnoop.com/api/trackers.php?hash={$hash}&json=1";
    $resultado = file_get_contents($apiURL);
    return $resultado;
}

$torrent = new Torrent('tails-i386-1.2.3.torrent'); // Especifique o arquivo torrent aqui
$torrentHash = $torrent->hash_info(); // HASH do arquivo torrent

$SeedsLeechs = obterSeedLeech($torrentHash);
$SeedsLeechs = json_decode($SeedsLeechs);
$seeds = $leechs = 0;

if (is_array($SeedsLeechs)){
    foreach($SeedsLeechs as $anuncios){
        $leechs += $anuncios->NUM_LEECHERS;
        $seeds += $anuncios->NUM_SEEDERS;
        echo "Anúncio: ". $anuncios->ANNOUNCE. " Seed: ". $anuncios->NUM_SEEDERS. " Leech: ". $anuncios->NUM_LEECHERS. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    // Fazer algo aqui caso não seja retornado as informações da hash.
}

//echo "Total de seeds: ". $seeds. "<br>";
//echo "Total de leechs: ". $leechs. "<br>";
```

Comment: Olá, como eu devo fazer chamar a API no meu codigo ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia Não entendi, basta trocar no código acima onde tem `"HASH AQUI"` pelo *hash* do seu *torrent*, para obter ele, basta usar o `$torrent->hash_info()`, [**olhe aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63365/6454)

Comment: Sim, fiz isso, porem não teve resultado nenhum, poderia me mostrar um exemplo de como ficou o seu ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia Olhe [**esse exemplo**](http://pastebin.com/iBJs1vXq).

Comment: Apareceu uma lista de Trackers informando a Seed e Leeecher de cada Tracker, agora como faço para somar tudo ??

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema.